# Replay kit not recording the second app from the parent app

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I have implemented Replaykit in my current app. 
My current app accesses another app, whose operation is to be recorded by Replaykit.

But When I am recording through Replaykit, it is recording the operations of only the parent app, and not the child app.

So how can I record the child app called from the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to post some code. It is possible that the child app is not on a layer that is being recorded by Replaykit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by the way you approach. Before iOS12, you can't initiate a video recording of other app from your app. Currently the only way you can do is to use `upload extension`, which should be initiated from control center by user to record entire screen of the device regardless what app is running. So.. Replay Kit only record it's current app screen, whenever the app becomes background, the recording will be stopped and that's by-design.